# Nullable (of date) things to consider when converting

Tags: vb.net, date, nullable

I have been asked to find out why an ajax call doest work if date fields are left blank on a web form, finding out was easy, its because the `VB` function expects an object with a Date type.

I'm going to convert these values to `Nullable(Of Date)`, but I'm reluctant as this is a class that's quite heavily used and I don't want to break anything else.

My thinking however is that everything calling this class must be sending in a correct Date or it would throw an error currently, so I should be ok.

As long as I check for a value using `HasValue` and get the date out using `Value` then I shouldn't have any problems, or is there something else I need to consider?

Comment: The problem is not clear. How are you using this class, is the Date/Nullable(Of Date) a (public) property or what is the interface? Is it used from inside or also from outside of this assembly? Have you control over the code that is using it, can you change it? Why don't you change the type to `Nullable(Of Date)` and see what compiler errors you get?

Comment: I did that and Im going through the errors now. I just wanted to know the things I should consider, I guess one of them is how empty dates are currently handled

Comment: You can understand a `Nullable(Of T)` as a value type that can be null. So you can compare it with null or  with a normal date, both works(`dtNullable` is a `DateTime?`): `If dtNullable = Date.Today Then` or `If dtNullable Is Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I understand the theory behind nullables, though haven't used them extensively. I was just after some pointers and pitfalls to avoid from someone with experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change every reference to use the Date's Value property it will be no worse than what you have now. Then you can add the HasValue checks where you need to.

Comment: yes I suppose because the Value will fail, but this would have failed anyway if the date wasn't a date when it was passed.